# Turn an object to a square bracket string (not using JSON.stringify)

Tags: javascript, brackets, object-literal

I have this Javascript object (that is created on-the-fly by my plugin code):

```js
{
   "field": {
      "name": "Name",
      "surname": "Surname"
   },
   "address": {
      "street": "Street",
      "number": 0,
      "postcode": 0,
      "geo": {
        "city": "City",
        "country": "Country",   
        "state": "State"   
      }
   },
   "options": [1,4,6,8,11]
 }
```

I **don't** want to turn this object to a JSON string, but I want to turn this object into another object, but with each field represented by a string, like this:

```js
{
  "field[name]": "Name",
  "field[surname]": "Surname",
  "address[street]": "Street",
  "address[number]": 0,
  "address[postcode]": 0,
  "address[geo][city]": "City",
  "address[geo][country]": "Country",   
  "address[geo][state]": "State",   
  "options[0]":1,
  "options[1]":4,
  "options[2]":6,
  "options[3]":8,
  "options[4]":11
}
```

Scenario:

- I dont know how the original object will look like (or how deep it'll be), since it's part of a plugin and I have no idea how people will build their forms
- I'm going to put this new object inside a `FormData` object, if it would only accept objects, it would be easier, because JSON can't upload files, but `FormData` object can

Comment: *"I dont know how the original object will look like (or how deep it'll be)"*... sounds like you need a loop and recursion. What is your question? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: the code is part of a plugin, since other people will use it, I have no idea how people will build their forms. PHP can trasform `field['name']` to literally `$data['field']['name']`, and I want to keep it that way. I know I'll need a loop, but how to accomplish it without knowing the depth of the object, and at the same time, building the string

Comment: Should `options` be converted to `"options[0]": 1`, etc as well?

Comment: no, that could stay like that, since PHP accepts `options[]=1` and will assign the correct index for each element in the array

Comment: But if you add a value to `FormData`, it's converted to a string. So, `options` and  `[1,4,6,8,11]` become `options=1,4,6,8,11`. As an aside, why don't you want to use JSON? seems to be a much easier solution to transport structured data.

Comment: I'm curious: why don't you want to use JSON, which is a widely supported data format?

Comment: because JSON can't upload files, FormData can ;) indeed, that was a nice catch, so it would need to be `options[0]=1`

Comment: @Bergi: I think the OP talks about `File` objects.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah, OK. Still, you could  use a multipart request consisting of the files and a JSON file

Comment: sending binary data using JSON is overkill, base64 or escaping the bytes make the data 3 times bigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you need a [`for...in` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over the properties of the object and can use recursion to subsequently convert nested objects:

```
function convert(obj, prefix, result) {
    result = result || {};

    // iterate over all properties
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var value = obj[prop];
            // build the property name for the result object
            // first level is without square brackets
            var name = prefix ? prefix + '[' + prop + ']' : prop;
            if (typeof value !== 'object') {
                // not an object, add value to final result
                result[name] = value;
            }
            else {
                // object, go deeper
                convert(value, name, result);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Usage:
var converted_data = convert(data);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FGbN/)

<del>Still, I would recommend using JSON.</del>

If you want to handle files as well, you might have to add an additional check for `File` objects. You'd want them raw in the result object:

```
else if (window.File && value instanceof File) {
    result[name] = value;
}

// and for file lists

else if (window.FileList && value instanceof FileList) {
    for (var i = 0, l = value.length; i < l; i++) {
        result[name + '[' + i + ']'] = value.item(i);
    }
}
```

It could be that the `File` (`FileList`) constructor is named differently in IE, but it should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of reinventing the wheel, so here is how you could answer your question using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's a great tool for data processing - once you wrap your head around it that is.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const convert = (haystack) => objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ key, value, isLeaf, context }) => {
    if (isLeaf) {
      const k = key.map((e, idx) => (idx === 0 ? e : `[${e}]`)).join('');
      context[k] = value;
    }
  }
})(haystack, {});

const data = { field: { name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname' }, address: { street: 'Street', number: 0, postcode: 0, geo: { city: 'City', country: 'Country', state: 'State' } }, options: [1, 4, 6, 8, 11] };

console.log(convert(data));
/* =>
  { 'options[4]': 11,
    'options[3]': 8,
    'options[2]': 6,
    'options[1]': 4,
    'options[0]': 1,
    'address[geo][state]': 'State',
    'address[geo][country]': 'Country',
    'address[geo][city]': 'City',
    'address[postcode]': 0,
    'address[number]': 0,
    'address[street]': 'Street',
    'field[surname]': 'Surname',
    'field[name]': 'Name' }
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)